# Python-Install Pytorch Point3D

Tags: python, pytorch

**I have a problem when install Pytorch Point3D in Python**

```
(base) C:\Users\My Pc>pip install torch-point3d
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch-point3d (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch-point3d

(base) C:\Users\My Pc>pip install torch-points3d
Collecting torch-points3d
  Using cached torch_points3d-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (307 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: torch-geometric<2.0.0,>=1.3.2 in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from torch-points3d) (1.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: torch-scatter<3.0.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from torch-points3d) (2.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pytorch_metric_learning<0.10.0,>=0.9.87.dev0 in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from torch-points3d) (0.9.92)
Requirement already satisfied: wandb<0.9.0,>=0.8.18 in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from torch-points3d) (0.8.36)
Requirement already satisfied: torch-sparse<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from torch-points3d) (0.6.7)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<3.0,>=2.1 in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from torch-points3d) (2.3.0)
Collecting numba<0.50.0,>=0.49.0
  Using cached numba-0.49.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (2.2 MB)
Collecting torch-cluster<1.5.6
  Using cached torch_cluster-1.5.5.tar.gz (37 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Anaconda\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\My Pc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d6d1644l\\torch-cluster\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\My Pc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d6d1644l\\torch-cluster\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\My Pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-u5a0ogxr'
         cwd: C:\Users\My Pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d6d1644l\torch-cluster\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\My Pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d6d1644l\torch-cluster\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        import torch
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 116, in <module>
        raise err
    OSError: [WinError 182] The operating system cannot run %1. Error loading "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\caffe2_detectron_ops_gpu.dll" or one of its dependencies.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Please help me.

Comment: are you using anaconda?

Comment: Yes, I'm using anaconda